# How to display related data on selecting a particular data from dropdown list from API using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to display the coordinators name automatically based on the dropdown list selection. All the data comes from API. So the list in the dropdown is the `emailAddress` from the below json data and based on choosing a particular login id, its respective `firstname` should be automatically displayed in the coordinators name part.

For example: I choose ***vp2@vp2.com*** from dropdown, firstname ***vp2*** should be automatically displayed in coordinators Name part.Below is the API json data and screenshot. I am able to get the details in the dropdown but I need suggestions on how to display the relative name automatically using Angular.js 1.

```
   {
    "users": [
{
  "_id": "583ff900836f861d7b94dac3",
  "emailAddress": "VP2@VP2.com",
  "lastName": "VP2",
  "firstName": "VP2"
},
{
  "_id": "58429971836f860e87083f2c",
  "emailAddress": "VP3@VP3.com",
  "lastName": "VP3",
  "firstName": "VP3"
}
             ]
   }
```

[image: Screenshot for coordinatorname]

**index.html file**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                                    <th>Coordinators Type</th>
                                    <th>Coordinators Type ShortName</th>
                                    <th>Coordinators LoginID</th>
                                    <th>Coordinators Name</th>
                                    <th>Coordinators image</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.coordinatorType" required/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.coordinatorTypeShortName" required/></td>
                                    <td><select ng-model="personalDetail.coordinatorId" ng-options="collegeCoordsList._id as collegeCoordsList.emailAddress+' - '+collegeCoordsList.fullName for collegeCoordsList in hodAdminCoordinators" ng-click="getCoordinatorName(personalDetail.coordinatorId)"></select></td>
                                    <!-- <td><input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.coLoginid" required/></td> -->
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.coordinatorName" required/></td>
                                    <td><img src="{{hodList.imageUrl}}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**getting coordinators list in dropdown**

```
   $http.get('https://student.herokuapp.com/college/coordinators/timeCoordinator')

        .success(function(response){

            coordinatorLength=response.users.length;

            for(var i=0;i<coordinatorLength;i++)
            {

                $scope.hodAdminCoordinators.push({  "_id":response.users[i]._id,
                                                    "emailAddress":response.users[i].emailAddress,
                                                    "lastName":response.users[i].lastName,
                                                    "firstName": response.users[i].firstName }); 
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-change on the select instead of ng-click.

```
<select ng-model="personalDetail.coordinatorId" ng-options="collegeCoordsList._id as collegeCoordsList.emailAddress+' - '+collegeCoordsList.fullName for collegeCoordsList in hodAdminCoordinators" ng-change="setCoordinatorName(personalDetail)"></select>
```

Inside your controller you can select the coordinator using a filter and assign the firstName to the firstName of the personDetail

```
$scope.setCoordinatorName = function(personalDetail){
   var coord = $scope.hodAdminCoordinators
      .filter(function(co){
         return co._id === personalDetail.coordinatorId
       })[0];

    personDetail.firstName = coord.firstName;
}
```

Not sure why you are looping through your resultset. Why not just assign the users to hodAdminCoordinators. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Hey it is not working. Can you tell me what is .filter on third line of controller part? using loop since need to push every required value into array.

Comment: It returns the items that match the condition. I created a plunk for you. +

Comment: Hey I have done for 2 dropdowns using what you said. But for third dropdown I am getting error "firstname is undefined" on line 15 of codepen http://codepen.io/vishalheble/pen/jVePLv

Comment: If the filter returns no results that would mean you are trying to access a property on a non existing object. That's why you are getting the error. Basically it means that it can't find a teacher with that id.

Comment: Not sure. If you can reproduce it in a plunker I might be able to help.